# NodeJS on Elastic Beanstalk giving CORS error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup a Node API on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. On the front-end I have a React App spun up on AWS Amplify. Now, when I try to fetch a register or signup hitting my API on a custom subdomain setup I get the following error in the front-end console.

**Access to fetch at 'https://api.mydomain.com/login' from origin 'https://app.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

I have tried to do everything possible but haven't been able to run it.

Could someone please help?

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
// const nodemon = require("");
// const auth = require("./auth");

//Web Server
const app   = express();
const port  = process.env.PORT;
const http  = require('http').Server(app);

//Web Server - Optimization
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}));
const corsOptions = {
    origin: ['https://app.mydomain.com']
  }    
  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','Content-Type','Authorization');
    next(); 
})

const Jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const jwtKey = 'th-connect';
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');

require('./db/config'); 
const User = require('./models/Users');

//Health Check
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is Online - Version 2.0 running on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: you have to configure your backend for accepting cors request from the `https://app.mydomain.com`. what is the backend you are using ?

Comment: It's a Node Server spun up on Elastic Beanstalk with a custom domain setup api.mydomain.com

Comment: with express as backend ?

Comment: yes with express as the backend

Comment: Interestingly the server is running on the root but when I try to make a post request it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure cors in you backend express code.

Before using you have to install cors `npm i cors`

```
const app = express()    
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['https://app.mydomain.com']
}    
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

You can see the official [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).
In the `origin` array you can add the `domains` for which you want to enable `cors`

Comment: Have done that still not working.

Comment: can you share your backend code...ensure `app.use(cors())` is before the other route declarations

Comment: I have just tried that as well but now the EB has gone degraded. Here is the code:

Comment: Shared the code in the question

Comment: hope you are not missing `app.listen(PORT)`. don't put so many `cors`. just keep one at the beginning.

Comment: Yes yes have that in the end :)

Comment: then remove the `app.options` middleware...there is no need for that if you are using cors, please clean up the things and try

Comment: I have cleaned the code and researched on the issue here: https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/#enable-cors-on-server-side